# Virtualbox 6.0.4 or 5.138 not working with Kernel 4.4.0-143-generic Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, xubuntu, dkms

[image]Well, it's very annoying, I have looking every where for a solution to get Virtualbox Windows 7 VM working on Xubuntu Kernel 4.4.0-143-generic , BUT NOWAY
it not works !!! My solution was change the default kernel boot to 4.4.0-141-generic and it works fine. Of course it's a BUG, the kernel 4.4.0-143-generic can't find vboxdrv, when try to run `modprobe vboxdrv`it gives an error that the drive is missing, vboxusers is set correctly, the virtualbox KEYS are assigned correctly, I tried VB 5.138 which uses dkms then remove and purge it and install from Oracle webpage VB 6.04 which not uses dkms. So it's very frustrating. So, any comments that can help me run VB on -143-generic kernel ? thanks, Vladi

Attached image of VB log file under kernel -143

Comment: They all use dkms. What does `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` show?

Comment: Did you install this one? https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.4/virtualbox-6.0_6.0.4-128413~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I tried this VB version (6.0.4-12843), No success . I'm telling you it's a BUG, kernel -0141 generic works flawless but -0143-generic NOT, How staff from Ubuntu release a new kernel with this bug, do they can't compare a new build kernel with the preview one and check the differences before release    ??

Comment: @vladimirpavloski could you please lower the current rant level and prepare bug report next time by yourself? I have reported bug and confirmed it (see my answer below). And what is even worse - you are using **kernel from *xenial-proposed***, so it is **not officially released (yet)**, but you requesting the full support of this package.

Comment: It's not clear for me what didn't work. Additions should be installed not from Ubuntu repos but from the iso provided. Everything works fine for me.

Comment: @N0rbert ok, I'm sorry for my behavior, I didn't payed attention that the kernel is not officially released.

Comment: You seem to have created multiple accounts. Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts so you can merge your accounts and be able to edit your posts without needing to go through review.

Answer (score 1):

I have host with VirtualBox 5.1.38 and guest running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with 4.4.0-143-generic kernel from *xenial-proposed*.

I can confirm that installing guest additions from `virtualbox-guest-x11` APT package does not work. I have the following error message after login:

> [image: VBoxClient: Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service, rc=VERR_ACCESS_DENIED]

So I have reported [bug 1818148 to LaunchPad.net](http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1818148). And I have discovered that 4.4.0-142-generic is also affected.

---

But installation from [`VBoxGuestAdditions_5.1.38.iso`](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.38/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.1.38.iso) works on my guest system.
What is bad - this way is breaking recommendation given in [similar Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1108218/66509) before.

---

**Update: the real [bug is 1818049](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1818049), it was reported on 2019-02-28 10:57:21 UTC.**

Comment: I'm another confirmation. I rolled back just now to 4.4.0-142 and the problem went away. https://askubuntu.com/a/1127079/1698

Comment: @Volomike I did the same. That seems to be the only solution available currently.

Answer (score 0):

This has been [fixed](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18315) in the [test builds](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds) of VirtualBox but not yet in the [releases](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) (at the time of writing).