# VirtualBox 6.0.14 not working with kernel 5.3.0-24-generic

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

- Host system: Ubuntu 19.10
- VirtualBox version: 6.0.14_Ubuntur132055
- Guest system: Ubuntu 16.04

I'm getting "VBoxClient: Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service, rc=VERR_ACCESS_DENIED" in an alert when I turn the machine on. The Ubuntu UI seems to load, but it won't capture my cursor or keyboard.

Inspired by [this answer about kernel 4.4](https://askubuntu.com/a/1122086/652834).

Comment: I'd give VB 6.1 a try.

Comment: Are you using a Ubuntu intended kernel? or just a testing kernel (without Ubuntu patches).  Also where are you using the Ubuntu packaged version (most prior issues user have is with the non-Ubuntu packaged version)

Comment: Solved by upgrading to VB 6.1. It isn't yet available in the standard Ubuntu apt repos, so I had to download it from the website. guiverc -- I'm using the standard Ubuntu kernel.